# What is a standard location for Typesafe Config file in a project directory structure?

Tags: java, scala, configuration, typesafe-activator

I'm a newbie to Scala and the JVM.

I've created a project via [Typesafe Activator](https://typesafe.com/activator), and I'm adding configuration to it using [Typesafe Config](https://github.com/typesafehub/config).

The documentation for Typesafe Config says that I can put the config file anywhere on the classpath under [a number of different names](https://github.com/typesafehub/config#standard-behavior).

Is there a standard location for each of these files?

I am also unfamiliar with determining or modifying the classpath for such a project, but that may be a separate question.

EDIT:  Here is the directory structure

```
/home/d/projects/test/minimal-scala1/
▸ lib/
▸ project/
▾ src/
  ▾ main/
▸ scala/
  ▸ test/
▸ target/
  activator*
  activator-launch-1.2.3.jar
  activator-sbt-echo-akka-shim.sbt
  activator.bat*
  build.sbt
  LICENSE
```

Comment: src/main/resources/application.conf

Comment: @AmigoNico make it an answer so I could upvote it (and the OP may once have accepted it).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Short Answer

#### If you are developing a third party lib to be used by other projects

src/main/resources/reference.conf

#### If you are developing a regular application

src/main/resources/application.conf

### Long Answer

- system properties
  Not a file obviously. You can specify them on command line when starting the app
  `sbt -Dmy.property=value run`
- application.conf
  src/main/resources/application.conf
- application.json
  src/main/resources/application.json
  Note: .conf format is more commonly used, you can skip this file.
- application.properties
  src/main/resources/application.properties
  Note: .conf format is more commonly used, you can skip this file.
- reference.conf
  src/main/resources/reference.conf
  Note:
  Although it is meant to be provided by third party libs, but nothing prevents you from using the file in regular applications.